# mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, vmware, nmap

I'm using UBUNTU 14.04 as virtual machine  on Windows using VMWARE ,
after logging I installed nmap but after trying to run

```
nmap -sP 10.42.0.0
```

I get the following message

```
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
```

I'm using

> Nmap version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

any hints ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "on windows." What DNS servers do you expect to be configured? Include diagnostic output regarding your DNS setup: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @bonsaiviking sorry i corrected it ... the file doesn't show anything just 2 lines of information and they are commented , i don't know if the problem come from using ubuntu as a virtual machine

Comment: @Frankenstein: Can anything (but itself and the host system) be `ping`ed from your virtual machine by IP?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi no i can't ping anything

Comment: @Frankenstein: Then it’s a network connectivity problem, and DNS is irrelevant. Which efforts did you apply to route or bridge your virtual machine to the outside world? By the way, Ī̲ start to think it’s a Windows question.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi well i don't know , i haven't made any efforts  to route or bridge my virtual machine to the outside world because i was thinking that it must be done automatically , please if you know to how to setup up the it will be much helpfull for me

Comment: 1. Are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are specifying the host with a ip address (eg, x.x.x.x)

It seems that the system you're running it from doesn't have a normal DNS file, */etc/resolv.conf*.
So, You can create a default nameserver with any IP (e.g. 6.7.8.9) using following command:

```
# echo "nameserver 6.7.8.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

This will set up a default nameserver.

Alternately you can specify it on `nmap` command without touching the system's configuration.

```
# nmap --dns-servers 6.7.8.9  x.x.x.x
```